# Aggregate values from first and last row

Tags: mysql, select, join, aggregate

I have a USERS table.

Each user has connections in a CONNECTIONS table.

Each connection has a datetime and some referenced properties like timezone, stored in a TZ reference table.

I'd like to select the userID, and the TimeZoneLabel for the first and the last connection. Even if a user has no connection (so NULL or anything else would be displayed)

Do something like :

```
Select USERS.id,
min(TZ.label),
max(TZ.label)

from USERS
join CONNECTION on USERS.id = CONNECTIONS.userid
join TZ on TZ.id = CONNECTIONS.tzid

group by USERS.id
order by max(CONNECTIONS.dateconn)
```

But I can't achieve doing that. I've found articles on the net about that, but nothing works when I try. The example above does not work for the label, as there are no real min / max values but the one used on the first CONNECTION and the one used on the last one.

And I have many of these in my real request so I'd like to avoid too many sub-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the timezones:

```
SELECT 
       u.id             AS userId
     , MIN(c.dateconn)  AS firstConnectionDatetime
     , MAX(c.dateconn)  AS lastConnectionDateTime
FROM Users AS u
  LEFT JOIN Connection AS c
    ON u.id = c.userid    
GROUP BY u.id    
ORDER BY lastConnectionDateTime
```

With timezones (assuming `Connection` table has `id` as `Primary Key`):

```
SELECT 
       u.id             AS userId
     , ConMin.dateconn  AS firstConnectionDatetime
     , ConMax.dateconn  AS lastConnectionDateTime
     , TzMin.label      AS firstTimeZoneLabel
     , TzMax.label      AS lastTimeZoneLabel
FROM Users AS u
  LEFT JOIN Connection AS ConMax
    ON ConMax.id =
        ( SELECT c.id
          FROM Connection AS c
          WHERE u.id = c.userid 
          ORDER BY c.dateconn DESC
          LIMIT 1
        )
  LEFT JOIN TzMax
    ON TzMax.id = ConMax.tzid
  LEFT JOIN Connection AS ConMin
    ON ConMin.id =
        ( SELECT c.id
          FROM Connection AS c
          WHERE u.id = c.userid 
          ORDER BY c.dateconn ASC
          LIMIT 1
        )
  LEFT JOIN TzMin
    ON TzMin.id = ConMin.tzid
```

A compound `(userid, dateconn, id)` index on `Connection` table would help performance.

Comment: Easy... :-) But the problem IS the timezone. I edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine, you're a master. There were days I was looking for such a solution !

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of explaining to go with this answer -- the actual query you're after is down the bottom.

This is an instance of selecting not only the max/min-field-per-group, but also the other fields corresponding to it.

The canonical way to do this is by `LEFT JOIN`-ing the table to itself.
For example, to pick the entire row corresponding to the most recent connection from `CONNECTIONS`, you'd do:

```
SELECT c.userid, c.tzid as latestTZ, c.dateconn as latestConn
FROM CONNECTIONS c
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c2 ON c.userid=c2.userid AND c.dateconn<c2.dateconn
WHERE c2.dateconn IS NULL
ORDER BY c.userid;
```

This essentially joins `CONNECTIONS` to itself on `userid`, and forms every possible pair of connection dates within that userid where `c.dateconn<c2.dateconn`. If there is no row in `c2` that has a greater date than `c`, then you've picked the largest (ie most recent) date.
The `JOIN` ensures that you also pick the rest of the corresponding row from the table.

With this in mind, this is how we'd select the first connection date and label for every user (with `NULL` if they've never connected. If you don't want that behaviour (ie only show users who have connected) then you can ignore the `USERS` table entirely).

```
SELECT u.id,c.dateconn as firstConnection,TZ.label AS firstTZ
FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c ON u.id=c.userid
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c2 ON c.userid=c2.userid AND c.dateconn > c2.dateconn
LEFT JOIN TZ ON c.tzid=TZ.id
WHERE c2.dateconn IS NULL;
```

To select the latest is the same, except you reverse the `>` to a `<`:

```
SELECT u.id,c.dateconn as latestConnection,TZ.label AS latestTZ
FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c ON u.id=c.userid
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c2 ON c.userid=c2.userid AND c.dateconn < c2.dateconn
LEFT JOIN TZ ON c.tzid=TZ.id
WHERE c2.dateconn IS NULL;
```

Your query is a little more complicated in that you want to select not just the min or the max, but *both* the min *and* the max.

### Solution

I think you might be able to `UNION` the previous two queries, OR you could do it all in one foul hit by basically `JOIN`-ing the two queries together:

```
# MIN & MAX
SELECT u.id, c.dateconn as firstCon, TZ.label as firstTZ, 
             c3.dateconn as latestCon, TZ2.label as latestTZ
FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c ON u.id=c.userid
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c2 ON c.userid=c2.userid AND c.dateconn > c2.dateconn
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c3 ON c.userid=c3.userid AND c3.dateconn >= c.dateconn
LEFT JOIN CONNECTIONS c4 ON c3.userid=c4.userid AND c3.dateconn < c4.dateconn
LEFT JOIN TZ ON TZ.id=c.tzid
LEFT JOIN TZ TZ2 ON TZ2.id=c3.tzid
WHERE c2.dateconn IS NULL
AND c4.dateconn IS NULL
ORDER BY u.id;
```

The `(c,c2)` pair find the first connection date/timezone, and the `(c3,c4)` pair find the latest.

Also, the join to `c3` doesn't actually need the `c3.dateconn>=c.dateconn` quantifier (all it needs is to join on `userid`), but it extra bit narrows down the rows we have to join on. This is because since we're looking for a latest (ie MAX) date in the `(c3,c4)` tables, and `c` contains the MIN date, we only need to look at rows for which the MAX date is >= the MIN date.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of JOIN try LEFT JOIN. 
Also before the ORDER BY add a GROUP BY USERS.id